# Writing to a .PGM file using C++

Tags: c++, pgm

For some reason, I can't write anything to a .PGM file. The following code compiles without errors but nothing is written to the .PGM file it creates. I'm fairly new to C++ and pretty unfamiliar with working with strings in this syntax.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

int main(){
// Initialize variables.
    const int ncols = 30;
    const int nrows = 20;
    const int maxval = 255;
    std::string filename;

// Prompt user for filename.
    std::cout << "What would you like to name the file of the PGM image? Please include .PGM at the end of your name." << std::endl;
// Uses getline() function to retrieve input from user into a string.
    std::getline(std::cin, filename);
// Creates output stream object to use with managing the file.      
    std::ofstream fileOut(filename.c_str(),std::ios_base::out
                          |std::ios_base::binary
                          |std::ios_base::trunc
               );
    fileOut.open(filename.c_str());
    fileOut << "P2" << " " << ncols << " " << nrows << " " << maxval << "\n";

    fileOut.close();
}
```

I know there is another SO question similar to this one, but I used that answer to get here. I can't even get it to write the header part and that's not even the point of the assignment. Can anyone help?

Comment: FYI, You're opening the file twice. Once when you construct `fileOut`, and a second time when you call `fileOut.open(...)`.

Comment: Removing the second time fixed it. Thank you so much.